# Any journal on OR Education

Tags: journals

Is there any recommendation in any journal or learning material (like some kind of tutorials) specified in Operation Research/Management Science/Quantitative Analysis/or similar? For example, I found it interesting to read [INFORMS Journal Transaction of Education](https://pubsonline.informs.org/journal/ited).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check out the [Decision Sciences Journal of Innovative Education](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/15404609).